# Creating a clone function in a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, 2d, clone

I am currently at the beginning of working on an assignment for a class to replicate the sliding brick puzzle. It has been a few years since I have use C++, so I am attempting to relearn and do the assignment all at once. I study bioengineering and use MATLAB all of the time, but its also hard for me to adjust to C++ in the few computer science classes that I take.

My question is for the clone function that I have to make. I am currently having issues with my debugger, so when I attempt to run the program it just crashes and I do not know why. The clone function, just as the name suggests, is supposed to create a clone of the class object. My code is provided below for your reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct move
{
    int piece;
    char direction;
};

class SBP
{
public:
    vector< vector<int> > state;
    int width; //columns
    int height; //rows

    void load(string filename);
    void display();
    SBP clone();
};

void SBP::load(string filename)
{
    int rownum = 1;
    char n;
    string str;
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    getline(file, str);
    width = str[0]-'0';
    height = str[2]-'0';
    while (getline(file, str))
    {
        vector<int> row;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        {
            n = str[i];
            if (n != ',')
            {
                if (n == '-')
                {
                    row.push_back((str[i + 1] - '0')*(-1));
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (str[i + 1] == ',')
                        row.push_back(n - '0');
                    else
                    {
                        row.push_back((str[i] += str[i + 1]) - '0');
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        state.push_back(row);
        rownum = rownum + 1;
    }
    printf("File has been loaded.\n\n");
}

void SBP::display()
{
    int num;
    printf("The state of the game is: \n");
    printf("%i,%i,\n", width, height);
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
        {
            num = state[r][c];
            printf("%i,", num);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

SBP SBP::clone()
{
    SBP clonestate;
    clonestate.width = width;
    clonestate.height = height;
    for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c)
            clonestate.state[r][c] = state[r][c];
    }
    return clonestate;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string filename = argv[1];
    SBP puzzle, clonestate;
    puzzle.load(filename);
    puzzle.display();
    clonestate = puzzle.clone();
    clonestate.display();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can help me. This is just the beginning of the assignment and I'm not able to move on until I get this fixed. Thank you.

Comment: That class should not need a clone function.  It's all value-based so operator= should suffice

Comment: Copy constructors and assignment operators should do what you need. The only time I can think of that you need a clone function is when you're working with inheritance and may not know what it is you are holding.

Comment: Actually you should not even need to write a copy constructor or an assignment operator.  At least not with the way that class is defined.  The compiler-generated copy constructor and assignment operator should work just fine for you.  Try it yourself.  Create an SBP, load it up, and then do an assignment.  It should work.

Comment: Most definitely. Everything in the class is Rule of Three/Five compliant, so the Rule of Zero is in effect. Dropping a link on the subject for S K: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 0):

think you should resize before assign value in clone.

or you just use the default copy constructor as long as you do not have pointer member

```
SBP SBP::clone()
{
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: A general pattern to the `clone` function is to return a pointer to the cloned instance:  `SBP * SBP::clone() { return new (*this);}`.